# In Ruby or Rails, why is "include" sometimes inside the class and sometimes outside the class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

I thought

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Foo
```

is to add a "mixin" -- so that all methods in the Foo module are treated as methods of the ApplicationController.

But now I see code that is

```
include Bar

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Foo
```

So why is it outside of `ApplicationController`?  How is that different from the more common use of putting it inside of `ApplicationController`?

Comment: `include Bar` like this is a pernicious error - it'll change `ApplicationController` the way you want it to, but also change every other object in the application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, `include Foo` inside a class adds `Foo` to that class's ancestors and thus makes all of `Foo`'s instance methods available to instances of those class.

Outside of any class definition `include Foo` will add `Foo` to the ancestors of `Object`. I.e. it is the same as if you did `include Foo` inside the definition of the `Object` class. The use doing this is that all of `Foo`'s instance methods are now available everywhere.