# Ruby: What is the difference between writing extend outside the class and inside the class

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I have read this question at url [In Ruby or Rails, why is "include" sometimes inside the class and sometimes outside the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161428/in-ruby-or-rails-why-is-include-sometimes-inside-the-class-and-sometimes-outs). As per the answer of this question i am expecting the method `print2` of module `Calculation` should be accessible to the class `Addition` and `ABc` .but i am getting error as `undefined method`print2' for Addition:Class (NoMethodError)`

```
module Calculation
    def print2
        puts "print2"
    end
end


require '/home/sanjay/Desktop/m'

extend Calculation;

class Addition

end

class Abc 

end

Addition.print2
Abc.print2
```

Please explain why this error is comming??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The receiver of `extend` should be each class, so you want `Addition.extend Calculation` and `Abc.extend Calculation` (after the class definitions). The semicolon is not required.

```
module D
  def dog
    puts "woof"
  end
end

class A; end
A.extend D
A.dog #=> "woof"

class B; end
B.extend D
B.dog #=> "woof"
```

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that your `extend` (outside any class) extends the Eigenclass of main. Main being the instance of Object that is your current runtime environment. An Eigenclass is the class of an object whose only instance is the given object. Each object in Ruby has a Eigenclass. Nothing inherits from an Eigenclass. So your `extend` is not inherited to any other classes.

Comment: You are correct. Just ask Ruby: `self #=> main/ self.class #=> Object/ extend Calculation/ self.print2 #=> (prints) "print2"/ self.singleton_methods.include?(:print2) #=> true/ Object.new.print2 #undefined method `print2'.