# How does include module works inside vs outside the class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[In Ruby or Rails, why is "include" sometimes inside the class and sometimes outside the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161428/in-ruby-or-rails-why-is-include-sometimes-inside-the-class-and-sometimes-outs)

I already looked into the above one but one thing I can't understand is how a top-level `include` (i.e. outside a class body) turns an *instance method* into a *class method*:

For example:

```
module Human
  def living
    true
  end
end

include Human
```

Now according to the answer from the linked question above, that `include` makes the methods from `Human` accessible from all the files (correct me if I am wrong).

But why can I access the method as a *class method*, given that `living` is defined as an *instance method*?

```
Human.living
#=> true
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is **module**, not *model*. This question has got nothing to do with `ruby-on-rails`.

Comment: Could you have a go at clarifying your question a bit? Try to provide a [mcve] of the behaviour. `Model Human ...` is not valid code; I presume you meant `module Human`. What exactly do you mean by "the `living` method in `Human` module is not a `self` method... accessed by module name"? This is quite a confusing sentence to read, and I'm not 100% sure I understand what you meant exactly. Could you please write a few valid lines of code to demonstrate what you're talking about?

Comment: I've simplified your question. I hope I got it right.

Comment: @MrMoviesTamil: You are **never** outside a class. Even if you do a `ruby -e 'include Foo'`, you are inside a class. To see this, do a `ruby -e 'p self.class'`, which shows you what class this is.

Comment: You are not accessing this method as a "class method" you are accessing it an an instance method since `Human` is *an instance* of the class `Module` which inherits from `Object`. Technically speaking all the methods are instance methods it is just a matter of which class these methods are defined in that controls the callable context for these methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161484/477037):

> Outside of any class definition `include Foo` will add `Foo` to the ancestors of `Object`. [...] all of `Foo`'s instance methods are now available everywhere.

By including a module at the top level, you are effectively saying:

```
Object.include(Human)

# or

class Object
  include Human
end
```

What you are missing is that modules and classes are objects, too.

The methods an object responds to come from its ancestors, e.g.:

```
1.0.class.ancestors
#=> [Float, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

'abc'.class.ancestors
#=> [String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

or, for your module:

```
Human.class.ancestors
#=> [Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When you `include Human` at the top level, it adds that module to every object's ancestors:

```
include Human

1.0.class.ancestors
#=> [Float, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Human, Kernel, BasicObject]
#                                        ^^^^^

'abc'.class.ancestors
#=> [String, Comparable, Object, Human, Kernel, BasicObject]
#                                ^^^^^

Human.class.ancestors
#=> [Module, Object, Human, Kernel, BasicObject]
#                    ^^^^^
```

Some examples:

```
1.0.living   #=> true
'abc'.living #=> true
Float.living #=> true
Human.living #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on the question, but you can use an `extend self` inside your module if you want to access its methods as you would a class' class methods (or self methods as you called them).

Without `extend self`

```rb
module MyModule
  def hi; puts "hi"; end
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule

  def say_something
    MyModule.hi
  end
end

MyClass.new.say_something # => NoMethodError: undefined method `hi' for MyModule:Module
```

With `extend self`:

```rb
module MyModule
  extend self
  def hi; puts "hi"; end
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule

  def say_something
    MyModule.hi
  end
end

MyClass.new.say_something # => hi
```

Learn more about it here [Ruby: extend self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733124/ruby-extend-self)